# Create a new backup repository for elasticsearch using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-storage, elasticsearch-net

For my ES backups, I use the Azure repository plugin.  So far, I've just been using a scheduled task that uses CURL to issue my desired commands but I want to do this in a WebJob.  Using the NEST library, I see that I can request a new `.Snapshot()` which is the second half of what I've been doing but I want to periodically (every month) create a **full** backup.  So, before I invoke the snapshot, I make sure the current month's repository is created something like so:

`PUT _snapshot/es-2017-12
{
  "type": "azure",
  "settings": {
    "container": "elasticsearch-backups",
    "base_path": "60-2017-12"
  }
}`

Is there a NEST-based approach to doing this or do I just have to send a raw request?  If raw, so far, I've never needed to make a raw request, could this particular request even be made via a `RawQuery()`?  If so, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any who may come along w/ this question, Martijn Laarman of the NEST team provided me the solution here: [Create a new backup repository using NEST 6.0?](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2974)